# Linux umask difference between root and non-root user

Tags: linux, umask

My system is :

```
# uname -a
Linux Ubuntu 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I sudo to `root` :

```
$ sudo bash --norc # root here
bash-5.1# umask
0022
```

When I sudo to another user :

```
$ sudo -u another-user bash --norc
bash-5.1$ umask
0002
```

With `bash --norc`, I'm not reading user-wide initialization files.

How can we explain the difference ?

Comment: Found answer : https://serverfault.com/a/1126385